# StringBuilder.ToString() throwing out of memory reading 145M file

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I am calling StreamReader.ReadToEnd() on a file that is 145M in size. It is thrown an exception in StringBuilder.ToString(). I'm running in 32-bit mode.

This should not be a problem. It's big, but not that big. Any idea why this throws the exception?

And any suggested workarounds?

Comment: Maybe you're reading it into a string more than once?  We need a [mcve].  Also, and `OutOfMemoryException` can be thrown if a single *contiguous* block of memory can't be found.  It doesn't just mean "out of memory".

Comment: Maybe it *is* that big.

Comment: It also depends on your RAM size, .NET version, etc.

Comment: I have 16G physical memory. This only occurs in our MS Word AddIn and so a minimal example isn't possible. It is possible that there is no single contiguous block of memory. If so, any way to convert the StringBuilder to a string as opposed to copying the chars across?

Comment: Do you *really* need to load the entire file into memory? Why not stream through it reading line by line and doing the processing you need?

Comment: @ps2goat No, it has nothing to do with your physical memory.  OOM is a result of running out of virtual memory, not physical.

Comment: virtual (page file) memory is usually based on a percent of physical ram, unless modified by the user.

Comment: Trying my to allocate 100+ M inside Word 32 bit process is pretty much guaranteed to fil due to address space fragmentation. You need to change your approach

Comment: Check Task Manager to see what the memory usage is before and while app is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Memory-mapped files** enables programmers to work with extremely large files because memory can be managed concurrently, and they allow complete, random access to a file without the need for seeking.

```
var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"c:\ExtremelyLargeImage.data", FileMode.Open,"ImgA")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx